# Cannot GET/ error while opening my app

Tags: node.js

```
-> this is my server.js. while i am trying to open it by using node server, it is showing cannot get/.
```

-> as i am trying to open. it is showing cannot get/. I have routed all the links correctly. but still this issue is pertaining me. 
-> in my server it is showing mongodb connected and running. but whilw i open it it is showing cannot get/

```
     var express = require('express');
        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        var User = require('./app/models/user');
        var app = express();
        var jwt = require('jwt-simple') var _ = require('lodash') var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

        var secretkey = "supersecretkey"

        app.post('/session', function(req, res, next) {
          console.log(req.body.username);
          User.findOne({
            username: req.body.username
          }).select('password').exec(function(err, user) {

            if (err) {
              return next(err)
            }
            if (!user) {
              return res.send(401)
            }

            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, valid) {
              if (err) {
                return next(err)
              }
              if (!valid) {
                return res.send(401)
              } //var test = {username:user.username}; //console.log(user.username); var token = jwt.encode({ username: req.body.username}, secretkey) res.json(token)

            })

          })
        })

        app.get('/user', function(req, res, next) {
              var token = req.headers['x-auth'] console.log(token)
 var auth = jwt.decode(token, secretkey) 
//console.log(auth)
 User.findOne({ username: auth.username 
}, function(err, user) 
{ res.json(user) }) })

              app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
                    var user = new User({
                        username: req.body.username
                      }) bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
                          user.password = hash user.save(function(err, user) {
                            if (err) {
                              throw next(err)
                            } // res.send(201) res.json(user); }) })

                          })

    app.listen(3000)

->This is my app.js.

    "use-strict"

    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the express Router
    var morgan = require('morgan');

    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();

    /*app.use(morgan('dev'));*/

    app.use('/public/app/controllers/routes', router);
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
    })); // support encoded bodies
    app.use(require('./config/auth'))
    app.use('/api/users', require('./app/controllers/api/users'))
    app.use('/api/sessions', require('./app/controllers/api/sessions'))
    app.use('/api/products', require('./app/controllers/api/products'))
    app.use('/api/companies', require('./app/controllers/api/companies'))
    app.use('/api/stockists', require('./app/controllers/api/stockists'))
    app.use('/api/employees', require('./app/controllers/api/employees'))
    app.use('/api/sales', require('./app/controllers/api/sales'))
    app.use('/', require('./app/controllers/static'))

    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
    var server = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('App listening at the ', port);
    });

    require('./websockets').connect(server)
```

-> as i am trying to open. it is showing cannot get/. I have routed all the links correctly. but still this issue is pertaining me. 
-> in my server it is showing mongodb connected and running. but whilw i open it it is showing cannot get/

Comment: Why is there a POST handler inside a GET handler? Why do you also create the server inside your last POST handler?

Comment: get  handler is closed. post started after the closing of get.. server is created after the post handler